# Как вывести результат запроса из БД в QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

Пишу *desktop* приложение. В качестве графического интерфейса использую *Pyside6*, БД - *postgresql*, ORM - *sqlalchemy*. 
В таблице клиентов порядка 100 000 записей. На данный момент для вывода общего списка клиентов использую `QTableWidget`.

Текущий вариант заполнения таблицы:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        session = Session()
        System.all_clients = session.query(Client).order_by(Client.id)
        for client in System.all_clients:
            row = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.id}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.last_name}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.first_name}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.middle_name}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 4, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.gender}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 5, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.birth_date}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 6, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.privilege}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 7, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.phone}"))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 8, QTableWidgetItem(f"{client.email}"))
        session.close()
```

Вроде бы, `QTableView` работает быстрее. И было бы логично использовать его, используя фильтрацию по какому-либо столбцу (вместо выполнения очередного запроса). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести результат запроса в `QTableView`?

---

**Update 12.03.22 13:48**

Изменил в предложенном [S.Nick][1] варианте подключение к БД. Но коннекта нет.

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")  # !!! установите свое
db.setHostName("192.168.x.x")
db.setPort(5432)
db.setDatabaseName("database")  # !!! установите свое
db.setUserName("postgres")
db.setPassword("xxx")
db.open()
```

Хотя если сделать такую операцию:

```
dbliste = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()
print(dbliste)
```

То показываются следующие драйвера: `['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QPSQL']`

---

**Update 14.03.22 16:07**

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
# import psycopg2

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        # self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        # self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self.tableView, db)
        table_name = 'client'  # !!! установите свою таблицу
        self.model.setTable(table_name)
        self.model.select()

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.tableView, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        # self.model.setTable("client")  # !!! установите свою таблицу
        # self.model.select()

        self.comboBox.clear()
        for i in range(self.model.columnCount()):
            self.comboBox.addItem(self.model.headerData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal))

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.filter_table)

    def filter_table(self, text):
        filter = " {} LIKE '%{}%'".format(self.comboBox.currentText(), text) if text else text
        self.model.setFilter(filter)
        self.model.select()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")  # !!! установите свое
    # db = psycopg2.connect(dbname='masl_tmp', user='postgres',
    #                     password='secret', host='192.168.251.xxx')
    db.setHostName("192.168.251.xxx")
    db.setPort(5432)
    db.setDatabaseName("masl_tmp")  # !!! установите свое
    db.setUserName("postgres")
    db.setPassword("secret")
    # cursor = db.cursor()

    # print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())

    if not db.open():
        sys.exit(-1)

    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Пробовал подключиться через psycopg2. Все ок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов с использованием [**QTableView**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) + [**QSqlTableModel**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html)
выглядит так.

В этом случае следует использовать метод [**setFilter**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql                     # !!! установите свои импорты Pyside6


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.tableView, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.model.setTable("students")                                # !!! установите свою таблицу
        self.model.select()

        self.comboBox.clear()
        for i in range(self.model.columnCount()):
            self.comboBox.addItem(self.model.headerData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal))

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.filter_table)

    def filter_table(self, text):
        filter = " {} LIKE '%{}%'".format(self.comboBox.currentText(), text) if text else text
        self.model.setFilter(filter)
        self.model.select()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")                   # !!! установите свое
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db")                                # !!! установите свое
    
    if not db.open():
        sys.exit(-1)

    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> update 12.03.22 13:48 Изменил в предложенном S.Nick варианте подключение к БД. Но коннекта нет.

@MarcusStill, пожалуйста, вставьте все ваши водключения в мой пример
и покажите весь код, который вы пробуете запускать. 
И хорошо расскажите что у вас получается,
что вы наблюдаете, какие ошибки вы получаету и.т.д.

Также попробуйте :

```
...
db.setHostName("localhost").
...
```

---

```
... 
self.model = QSqlTableModel(self.tableView, db)
table_name = 'units'                   # !!! установите свою таблицу  
self.model.setTable(table_name)
self.model.select()
...
```

Comment: @MarcusStill что не так?

Comment: Прошу прощения, вчера не дал обратную связь. Обновил свой пост.

Comment: @MarcusStill я добавил некоторые обновления в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @s-nick Странно, внес 192.168.xxx.xxx localhost в host файл Windows. Не хочет ни по ip, ни к localhost`y подключаться. Запустил этот же файл (без вчерашних ваших правок) на машине с linux (на ней же в docker запущен postgresql) и все ок. Долгожданное окно появилось, красивое, с работающим фильтром. И, вроде бы, все 100к записей выводятся мгновенно. А чтобы отрисовать QTableWidget с этим же количеством юзверей, требуется примерно 14 сек. Печаль(

Comment: @s-nick
Спасибо за помощь! 
Как же починить на windows этот вариант отображения данных из БД.. На linux что-то проект в exe не конвертируется. А под windows процесс пошел. Теперь правда такая проблема нарисовалась.

Comment: @MarcusStill пожалуйста. У меня нет БД - postgresql и я не могу попробовать.

Comment: @s-nick Еще раз спасибо! Поставил psql и вместе с ним psqlODBC. И из каталога bin скопировал все dll в папку с проектом. И exe запустился, и py файл. Можете подсказать как правильно реализовать логику. У меня в один QTableWidget выводятся данные клиентов. Двойным щелчком я выбираю нужных и переношу в другой QTableWidget, из которого формирую продажу. Как правильно двойным щелчком мыши на строке в QTableView перенести данные из нее в QTableWidget?

Comment: @MarcusStill, если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приложите минимально-воспроизводимый пример и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.